# Publish Java App to Mac Store

Tags: java, macos, deployment, store

currently I am trying to create a signed paket installer with javapackager to publish my Java App in the Mac Store. This is, what I have done so far:

1. I have requested the certificate for  the app and the installer and  added them to the keychain
2. create the icon file
3. create the entitlements file (it’s just a test app, so only sanbox):

com.apple.security.app-sandbox

4. create PKG:

*javapackager -deploy -srcFiles Test.jar -native mac.appStore -BsystemWide=true -title Titel -name Name -outdir /Users/mac/Desktop/ -outfile temp -BappVersion=1.0.0 -appclass app.example.main -Bidentifier=app.example.main -Bicon=/Users/mac/Desktop/App.icns -Bmac.app-store-entitlements-path=App.entitlements -Bmac.category=public.app-category.business*

So far, so good ...

The task proceeds without problems, but when I try to upload the PKG file via Application Loader, I get the following error messages:

- ERROR ITMS-90511: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.oracle.java.8u131.jdk' of 'Name.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime' is already in use by another application."
- ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "app.example.main.pkg/Payload/Name.app/Contents/MacOS/Name", "app.example.main.pkg/Payload/Name.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jspawnhelper" )] Refer to App Sandbox page at .apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/ for more information on sandboxing your app."

The first error was easy to fix: I have just edited the bundle identifier in the plist to a unique one.
According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5L7Smt7Vgg) javapackager handles the whole sign process automatically. I have no influcence on this, so I am not sure what to do here ...

I generell there are not that much information on this topic, this is what I have found so far:

- speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/ --> same error
- intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/ --> AppBundler is not maintained anymore

Maybe anybody has experienced similar problems and can help me.

Thank you.

Jan

Comment: The javapackager docs say `mac.app-store-entitlements=path`, but you say `-Bmac.app-store-entitlements-path=...` -- does that make a difference?  What entitlements do you request?

Comment: "The -B option for the -deploy command is used to specify arguments for the bundler that is used to create self-contained applications. Each type of bundler has its own set of arguments." (Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) - without the B you will get an error ....

Comment: It's not the letter "B" that's funny.  It's the part that comes *after* it that's different.  The error message says that you're not requesting the necessary entitlement, so either it's not in your file (what's in it?), or it's not seeing your file (perhaps because it's spelled differently).

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't see that. However, I will get the same error messages with mac.app-store-entitlements=path. Content of the entitlements file:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>

Comment: @Jan I see a `;` symbol just after the doctype declaration. I think it shouldn't be there.